# I need help with creating linear equations from multiple points on a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do you create a linear equation from multiple points on a graph I am working on a question where the points are $(-3,8),(2,5)$ and $(7,2)$ and I need to find out how to create a linear inequality equation from this